# Binding ng-model conditional

Tags: angularjs, devexpress

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="addingNew|| chnagepwd">
            <label>Password</label>
            <div dx-text-box="txtPwdProperty"
                 dx-validator="txtPwdvalidator"
                 ng-model="userConfig.USER_PWD">
            </div>
</div>
```

Above Code i am using for saving password in user addition and editing.In addition it works fine.But in case of editing i don't want rebind password,but same time,i just need to save that into model when user entering value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of having the same view/controller for adding and editing an object. You'll have more trouble than gain. That said...

Why don't you just bind to another property in the scope?
Then apply the change to the model in the controller only when "adding" or "there is some text in the bound property"

```
ng-model="editModel.password"
```

and in th econtroller:

```
function init() {
    editModel = {
        password: ''
    }
}

function save() {
   ...
   if (adding || editModel.password) { 
      model.password = editModel.password;
   }
   ...
   actualSave();
}
```